# how to validate input type file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
<input id="document" type="file" multiple/>
 if($.trim($("#documnet").val()) === ""){
  alert("Upload Your document.");
  return false;
 }
```

But it is not working. And I want to upload only .zip extension.

Comment: #documnet is a typo in your code

Comment: why is below right answer ?... it does not tell you how to validate zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `document` as `documnet`

Comment: why is this right answer ?... it does not tell you how to validate zip file

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution, some non-desktop devices will show input fields, but not actually function. If your form will be used solely on desktop devices, this ins't a concern.

Though if your form is going to be used on other devices (mobile, tablet, smartTV), I'd recommend not having input[type=file] fields be required. It could make it impossible for those users to submit your form.